# How to mock inline function with lambda using Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito, mockito-kotlin

Have a problem with mocking the inline function with lambda. Have class `UserController`, trying to mock `tracer` with function `createSpan`.

UserController class:

```
class UserController(private val tracer:Tracer) {
  fun subscribeUser() {
    tracer.createSpan("GraphDB: subscribedUser") {
       do something...
    }
  }
}
```

`createSpan` inline function:

```
inline fun <T> Tracer.createSpan(operationName: String, block: SpanContext.() -> T): T =
    buildSpan(operationName)
        .start()
        .useOn(this, block)
```

Tried:

```
 Mockito.`when`(mockTracer.createSpan<Any>(any(), any())).thenReturn(mockSpanContext)
```

returns `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException`

```
 Mockito.`when`(mockTracer.createSpan<SpanContext>("GraphDB: subscribedUser", any())).thenReturn(mockSpanContext)
```

returns `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Tried different approaches but return only `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException` or `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

How can I mock this inline function with a lambda or just ignore it, because I don't want to test this function? Any help appreciated.

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer your question, we've adopted a standard of extracting giant lambda chains into their own functions with a good english name. This makes them individually testable, increases code clarity, and makes them testable.